# Swagger behind Nginx instead of Zuul

Tags: nginx, swagger, swagger-ui, nginx-reverse-proxy, netflix-zuul

How does Zuul make it swagger on http://foo-service:8080 works correctly for external access from http://public.com/foo-service ?

I have a task to replace Zuul with nginx (It's not my decision, I can't change it). I rewrite in nginx http://public.com/foo-service/names-controller/swagger-ui.html to http://foo-service:8080/names-controller/swagger-ui.html , but in swagger response I get broken links - without /foo-service/ that is I get http://public.com/names-controller... instead of http://public.com/foo-service/names-controller/....
With Zuul it was working fine out of the box - magic.

Is there any http request header Zuul is setting that is used by swagger?

How does Zuul make it Swagger works fine?

How could it be done in Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Hip Hip ...

`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /foo-service/;`

helps.